# Using a default implementation of typeclass method to omit an argument

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to be able to define a (mulit-parameter-) typeclass instance whose implementation of the class's method ignores one of its arguments. This can be easily done as follows.

```hs
instance MyType MyData () where
    specific _ a = f a
```

As I'm using this pattern in several places, I tried to generalize it by adding a specialized class method and adequate default implementations. I came up with the following.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class MyType a b where
    specific :: b -> a -> a
    specific = const dontCare
    dontCare :: a -> a
    dontCare = specific (undefined :: b)
    {-# MINIMAL specific | dontCare #-}
```

This however yields the error `Could not deduce (MyType a b0) arising from a use of ‘dontCare’` [..] `The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous`. I don't see why the latter should be the case with the type variable `b` being scoped from the class signature to the method declaration. Can you help me understand the exact problem that arises here?

Is there another reasonable way to achieve what I intended, namely to allow such trimmed instances in a generic way?

Comment: What if you remove the `::b`? So `dontCare = specific undefined`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but perhaps you can figure it out. I can make it compile by writing `specific = const (dontCare @a @b) ; dontCare = specific @a @b undefined`

Comment: em naming a class `MyType` doesn't make a lot of sense; it's a class not a type. What you seem to want is to ignore one of the class's type parameters. Then why even have it as a parameter to the class? `dontCare`'s signature only mentions param `a`; that's why you're getting the error message. Do you mean that given some instance for the class, `b`'s type can be derived from `a`'s? Then you want an 'Associated Type' or 'Type Family' or possibly 'Functional Dependency'. Look up those extensions in the User Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the default definition of `specific`. Let's zoom out for a second and see what types your methods are actually given, based on your type signatures.

```
specific :: forall a b. MyType a b => b -> a -> a
dontCare :: forall a b. MyType a b => a -> a
```

In the default definition of `specific`, you use `dontCare` at type `a -> a`. So GHC infers that the first type argument to `dontCare` is `a`. But nothing constrains its second type argument, so GHC has no way to select the correct instance dictionary to use for it. This is why you ended up needing `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to get GHC to accept your type signature for `dontCare`. The reason these "ambiguous" types are useful in modern GHC is that we have `TypeApplications` to allow us to fix them. This definition works just fine:

```
class MyType a b where
    specific :: b -> a -> a
    specific = const (dontCare @_ @b)
    dontCare :: a -> a
    dontCare = specific (undefined :: b)
    {-# MINIMAL specific | dontCare #-}
```

The type application specifies that the second argument is `b`. You could fill in `a` for the first argument, but GHC can actually figure that one out just fine.